# What does Total mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I read this sentence and it confuses me:

> "Consumption of coffee in USA totals in 4 Kg per person."

"USA totals" -- what does it mean?

Comment: In this case, it just means "amounts to" (4kg per person). The "in" is superfluous.

Comment: @Mick If "totals" is the main verb in that sentence (which I agree it is), then isn't the word "in" redundant ?

Comment: Yes, it is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sentence "Consumption of coffee in USA totals 4 Kg per person" (the "in" in " totals in 4 Kg" is superfluous), the subject is "consumption of coffee in [the] USA", and the main verb is "totals". Since "consumption" is singular, the verb is also singular, while USA is plural.

The verb "to total" here means "to amount to" (as Mick already suggested in a comment).

One would normally write, "Consumption of coffee in **the** USA totals 4kg per person."

Some other examples of the verb "total":

- "The latest available data estimates total alcohol consumption in the UK at 9.4 litres per head for those aged 15 years and older and 7.7 litres per head on average throughout the entire population in 2013." ([Institute of Alcohol Studies](http://www.ias.org.uk/Alcohol-knowledge-centre/Consumption/Factsheets/Total-consumption-in-the-UK.aspx))
- "In a meta-analysis of ten randomised controlled trials that lasted eight weeks or more, totalling 608 adults with type 2 diabetes, researchers found mixed results for the impact of drinking tea, ..." ([*The Independent*, 15 Dec. 2015](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/features/international-tea-day-five-healthy-reasons-to-put-the-kettle-on-a6773766.html))

You can also read the sentence as "In the USA, the total consumption of coffee per person is 4kg."

Comment: Is my sentence grammatically right?

Comment: The in is not redundant. It's a mistake: typo or unedited text.

Comment: @Lambie The "in" in " totals in 4 Kg" is redundant.

Comment: @Christophe Strobbe Redundant means repetition in the same phrase. Not later in the sentence: Consumption of coffee in USA totals in 4 Kg per person. Redundant would be: Consumption of coffee in and inside the USA totals 4 Kg per person. That is redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the total consumption of coffee in the U.S. is equal to four kilograms per person.

**to total** means to amount in number to a specified quantity.

Example:

> The amount of money I spent on learning English in the past year **totals $1,000**.

What this example says is that I have spent in total $1,000 on English in the past year.

As for the supposed redundancy of *in*, you can't total 4 kg per person. You total an amount of something. You need a quantity. 4 kg per person is not exactly a quantity. That's why you need that *in* there.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: The final "in" in the quoted sentence is ungrammatical, and a per-person total can be fine, as this alternative phrasing shows: "Per-person consumption of coffee in the USA totals 4 Kg".